# How to move an object diagonally in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective**

I need my app to move a view diagonally from the center of the screen to the bottom left edge.

**Code**

To do so, I am animating constraints.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {
        constraintBottomSpace.constant -= 10
        constraintLeadingSpace.constant -= 10

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in})
}
```

**Question**

The image doesn't move. How do I move an object diagonally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your constraints and call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` *before* the animation block.

Call `layoutIfNeeded()` *inside* the block.

For example:

```
func animateToCorner() {
    constraintBottomSpace.constant -= 10
    constraintLeadingSpace.constant -= 10

    view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(10, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: could you please recommend another way to move a view diagonally? The code we are using just seem to make the image bigger, which is not what we want to do. Thanks so much for your help again!

Comment: You might need to add +10 to your top and/or trailing constraints!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set constants of constraints like this:

```
constraintBottomSpace.constant = 0
constraintLeadingSpace.constant = 0
```

using -= 10 will move it only 10 pixels to the corner.

Or try without options like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: { () -> Void in

     constraintBottomSpace.constant = 0
     constraintLeadingSpace.constant = 0
}) { (finished) -> Void in

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! That's a good guess. I haven't thought of that. I tried fixing my code as you recommended, but I am still experiencing the problem. The image isn't moving. Do you think I should change `UIViewAnimationOptions ` to something different than `.Repeat` or `.CurveLinear`? Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest trying without using animation options, check my edited answer